# How to compare a value with a subquery in Laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, subquery, compare

I have a scope to filter the employees at one of the branches on a certain date. For this, I need a subquery like the following. 8 => a variable. I have no idea how to do this with Laravel Eloquent. Maybe someone can help me?

```
SELECT * FROM em_employments JOIN employees e on em_employments.employee_id = e.id
WHERE 8 = (
    select 'service_facility_id'
    from 'em_service_facility_relations'
    where 'date_from' <= '20222-01-01' and 'employee_id' = e.id 
    order by 'date_from' desc limit 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it the other way around. `WHERE <subquery> = <value>`

```php
DB::query()
    ->select('*') // optional
    ->from('em_employments')
    ->join('employees e', 'em_employments.employee_id', 'e.id')
    ->where(
        function ($sub) {
            $sub->select('service_facility_id')
                ->from('em_service_facility_relations')
                ->where('date_from', '<=', '20222-01-01')
                ->whereColumn('employee_id', 'e.id')
                ->orderByDesc('date_from')
                ->limit(1);
        },
        '=', // optional
        $value
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply! It works now. Many thanks! I have tried many things but I didn't think to try it the other way around.